# How to organize types definitions in a React Project w/ Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend

I have been using typescript in my projects for a month and there're some doubts that I'm struggling with.

Is there a pattern/recommended way to organize types in project architecture?

Let's suppose we have a context with the following interfaces:

```
export type ToastMessageType = 'info' | 'success' | 'error';

export interface ToastMessageData {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  type: ToastMessageType;
}

export interface ToastsStateContextData {
  messages: ToastMessageData[];
}

export interface ToastsDispatchContextData {
  addToast: (message: Omit<ToastMessageData, 'id'>) => void;
  removeToast: (id: string) => void;
}
```

And there's another component called `ToastMessage` that receives a `message` prop and has the type of `ToastMessageData`:

```
interface ToastMessageProps {
  message: ToastMessageData;
  style: React.CSSProperties;
}

const ToastMessage: React.FC<ToastMessageProps> = ({ message, style }) => {
```

I fell that it is weird to import an interface from a context inside of a component, so there's something wrong going on.

What do you guys recommend?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Generally, if the type alias/interface is specific only for the component, it is alright to write it within the same `.tsx` file, as you can consider them to be used "locally" for that component.

However, there can be scenarios when you need to reuse that type alias/interface across other components, or other helper files (For instance, the interface from component A extends the interface from component B). For this, it will be better to store the type alias/interface in a separate file. For instance, you could have a shared directly that houses all the common type aliases/interfaces that are to be exported.

```
- pages
  - ComponentA
  - ComponentB
- shared
  - interfaces
    - messages.interface.ts
    - geo.interface.ts
    // etc 
  - services
  - helper
  // etc
```

The main advantage of doing so, is that you will be able to prevent the risk of [cyclic dependencies](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-cycle.md), especially when you find out that you are writing code whereby multiple components are exporting and importing stuff from each other.

Comment: I think if you `import type` or `import typeof` the cyclic dependency issue is not encountered because it doesn't affect the runtime. It's in the ESLint docs linked above.